# function crosstab(unknown, unknown) does not exist but it does

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a crosstab function that I've used successfully many times in the past, but now it's dumping all the data at the end instead of pivoting it into the output table.  It can't seem to find Crosstab.  I've researched it doing the following;

- create extension if not exists tablefunc; --- answer is: extension "tablefunc" already exists
- create extension tablefunc with schema animals; answer is: as above
- select count(*) from information_schema.routines where routine_name like 'crosstab%';  ---- answer is 6.

The following is a section of the function code:
BEGIN
str := '" " text,';  -- blanks in A1 cell

FOR rec IN SELECT DISTINCT col_name
        FROM an_in_tbl
        ORDER BY col_name
    LOOP
    str :=  str || '"' || rec.col_name || '" text' ||',';
    END LOOP;

```
str:= substring(str, 0, length(str));

EXECUTE 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS an_out_tbl;
CREATE TABLE an_out_tbl AS
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(''select row_name, col_name, row_value from an_in_tbl order by 1'',   
             ''SELECT DISTINCT col_name FROM an_in_tbl ORDER BY 1'')
     AS final_result ('|| str ||')';
```

select animal_pivot_fn()

> NOTICE:  extension "tablefunc" already exists, skipping
>   NOTICE:  table "an_out_tbl" does not exist, skipping
>   ERROR:  function crosstab(unknown, unknown) does not exist
>   LINE 5:     FROM crosstab('select row_name, col_name, row_value from...
>                    ^
>   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>   QUERY:  CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;
>       DROP TABLE IF EXISTS an_out_tbl;
>       CREATE TABLE an_out_tbl AS
>       SELECT *
>       FROM crosstab('select row_name, col_name, row_value from an_in_tbl order by 1',
>                    'SELECT DISTINCT col_name FROM an_in_tbl ORDER BY 1')
>            AS final_result (" " text,"CAT" text,"DOG" text,"SNAKE" text,"HORSE" text,"ELEPHANT" text,"MOUSE" text,"MONKEY"... and many more... HERE IS WHERE THE DATA GETS DUMPED AND NO PIVOTED TABLE GETS CREATED.

Comment: It sounds like the schema where `tablefunc` is installed isn't in your [`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH)

Comment: I went to the schema where this routine had previously worked and copy these functions:

Comment: I went to the schema where this routine had previously worked and copied these functions in:   connectby (4 functions), crosstab (six functions).  I don't know how these files got there.  I don't think 'create extension if not exists tablefunc' is enough.  I must have done something additional to get them into that old schema.  So I just copied them into my new schema.  Now I have other issues like tables can have up to 1600 columns, which I knew about, so I know that's not the case ...

Comment: It sounds like different clients are using different `search_path`s. Whoever ran the `CREATE EXTENSION` first would have installed the extension in their default schema, and so they can just call `crosstab()` without qualifying it. Clients without that schema in their `search_path` will need to call `schema_name.crosstab()` instead. The solution is to install it in a known location, and either make sure it's in everyone's `search_path`, or make sure everyone qualifies their `crosstab()` calls with a schema name.

Comment: Thank you, Nick.

Answer (score 10):

Need to  run below query

Run `\dx` command .

[image]

if result  like  below need to  run following  query

```
 CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

[image]

Run `\dx` command again,result  should  be  like  below.

[image]

Now you can run crosstab query it should be solved.

Comment: add this query 
"CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;"
to your sql-script before using function CROSSTAB().